# SQL - Is it possible to join a table to a resultset created by several select/union-alls?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, union, union-all

I'm trying to find a workaround (hack) to some limitations preventing me from using a temporary table or a table variable in my SQL query.

I have a real table (technically it's a derived table that results from an UNPIVOT of a poorly designed table) which lacks several necessary fields.  I need to hardcode these fields into the result until we can cleanup the database issue.

Given a table like:

```
tblEntity
ID | Name
 1 |  One
 2 |  Two
```

I need to join several fields such as:

```
ID | Order
 1 |     2
 2 |     1
```

The join would result in:

```
ID | Name | Order
 1 |  One |     2
 2 |  Two |     1
```

My question is:  can I join tblEntity to a resultset created like:

```
SELECT 1, 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1
```

Is it possible to join?  If so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select te.*, t.Ord from tblEntity te
inner join (
    SELECT 1 as Id, 2 as Ord
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 1
) t on te.ID = t.Id
```

Answer (score 2):

Making a few assumptions, this would do it:

```
SELECT en.ID, en.Name, xx.OrderBy
 from tblEntity en
  inner join (select 1 Id, 2 OrderBy
              union all
              select 2,1) xx
   on xx.Id = en.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL-Server 2008, it's also possible to use **[`Table Value Constructors`](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/table-value-constructors-in-sql-server-2008/)**:

```
CREATE TABLE #tblEntity
( ID INT
, Name CHAR(10)
) ;

INSERT INTO #tblEntity
  (ID, Name)
VALUES
  ( 1, 'One' ) ,
  ( 2, 'Two' ) ;

SELECT 
    t.ID, t.Name, o.Ordr AS "Order"
FROM 
        #tblEntity AS t
    JOIN
        ( VALUES
             (1,2)
           , (2,1)
        ) AS o(ID, Ordr)
      ON o.ID = t.ID ;
```

You can test the above in: [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2283/table-value-constructors-solution-for-question-8528061)

Comment: I forgot about these. A bit awkward to use, but better than goofing around with UNIONs.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways of doing this e.g.

```
WITH T1 (Id, "Order")
     AS 
     (
      SELECT 1, 2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, 1
     )
SELECT e.*, T1."Order"
  FROM tblEntity e 
       JOIN T1 
          ON e.Id = T1.Id;
```

e.g. 2

```
SELECT e.*, T1."Order"
  FROM tblEntity e 
       JOIN (
             VALUES (1, 2), 
                    (2, 1)
            ) AS T1 (Id, "Order")
          ON e.Id = T1.Id;
```

e.g. 3

```
WITH T1 
     AS 
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 2), 
                     (2, 1)
             ) AS T (Id, "Order")
     )
SELECT e.*, T1."Order"
  FROM tblEntity e 
       JOIN T1 
          ON e.Id = T1.Id;
```

...and so on.